# Is it possible to upload a file as well as post data using servicestack?

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack, restsharp

I want to be able to post a file and as part of that post add data.

Here is what I have:

```
            var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            restRequest.Resource = "some-resource";
            restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            string request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            restRequest.AddParameter("text/json", request, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var fileModel = model as IHaveFileUrl;

            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileModel.LocalStoreUrl);

            restRequest.AddFile("FileData", bytes, "file.zip", "application/zip");


            var async = RestClient.ExecuteAsync(restRequest, response =>
            {
                if (PostComplete != null)
                    PostComplete.Invoke(
                        new Object(),
                        new GotResponseEventArgs
                            <T>(response));
            });
```

It posts the file fine but the data is not present - is this even possible?

[UPDATE]

I have amended the code to use the multi-part header:

```
            var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            Type t = GetType();
            Type g = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            restRequest.Resource = string.Format("/{0}", g.Name);
            restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            restRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");

            string request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            restRequest.AddParameter("text/json", request, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var fileModel = model as IHaveFileUrl;

            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileModel.LocalStoreUrl);

            restRequest.AddFile("FileData", bytes, "file.zip", "application/zip");


            var async = RestClient.ExecuteAsync(restRequest, response =>
            {
                if (PostComplete != null)
                    PostComplete.Invoke(
                        new Object(),
                        new GotResponseEventArgs
                            <T>(response));
            });
```

Still no luck... any pointers?

Comment: You would need the `content-type` set to `multipart/mixed` or `multipart/form-data` in the request header. Doing that you can access the request-body and the get the file from the request simultaneously.

Comment: Does anyone have any clues on this?

Comment: Did you also try with multipart/mixed?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296867/servicestack-client-add-attachment

Comment: That just shows uploading a file with no model no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is going to help. But give it a try.

Since you are attempting to pass it as text/json you may try to convert your byte array to a string and add it to the request.

To convert it to a string you may do something like this.

```
    public string ContentsInText
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(_bytecontents);
        }
    }
```

To convert it to a byte array you may do this. Most probably you will have to do this in your web service.

```
    public byte[] ContentsInBytes
    {
        get { return Encoding.Default.GetBytes(_textcontents); }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert in `C#` but I used the same principle in Grails/Java for multipart requests.

**Some pointers (ServiceStack/C#)**
[Multipart Form Post](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c)
[MSDN MIME Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526560%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx)
[ServiceStack File Attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296867/servicestack-client-add-attachment)

**Java corresponds:**
[Posting File and Data as JSON in REST Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-data-to-restful-webservice-as-json)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need to know specifically how to do this using restsharp (or servicestack - preferably restsharp) - thanks for your response though