# Run report from JasperServer using PHP SOAP client

Tags: php, soap, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to run a report from JasperServer using a PHP SOAP client.  I found this example online, but I want to attach an XML data source, used for the report data, and I am unsure how it should be correctly attached.

How can I attach my XML data source to the SOAP request, that is acceptable to Jasper Server?

```
  public function requestReport($report, $format, $params) {
    $params_xml = "";
    foreach ($params as $name => $value) {
      $params_xml .= "<parameter name=\"$name\"><![CDATA[$value]]></parameter>\n";
    }

    $request = "
      <request operationName=\"runReport\" locale=\"en\">
        <argument name=\"RUN_OUTPUT_FORMAT\">$format</argument>
        <resourceDescriptor name=\"\" wsType=\"\"
        uriString=\"$report\"
        isNew=\"false\">
        <label>null</label>
        $params_xml
        </resourceDescriptor>
      </request>
    ";

    $client = new SoapClient(null, array(
        'location'  => $this->url,
        'uri'       => 'urn:',
        'login'     => $this->username,
        'password'  => $this->password,
        'trace'    => 1,
        'exception'=> 1,
        'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_1,
        'style'    => SOAP_RPC,
        'use'      => SOAP_LITERAL

      ));

    $pdf = null;
    try {
      $result = $client->__soapCall('runReport', array(
        new SoapParam($request,"requestXmlString") 
      ));

      $pdf = $this->parseReponseWithReportData(
        $client->__getLastResponseHeaders(),
        $client->__getLastResponse());
    } catch(SoapFault $exception) {
      $responseHeaders = $client->__getLastResponseHeaders();
      if ($exception->faultstring == "looks like we got no XML document" &&
          strpos($responseHeaders, "Content-Type: multipart/related;") !== false) {
        $pdf = $this->parseReponseWithReportData($responseHeaders, $client->__getLastResponse());
      } else {
        throw $exception;
      }
    }

    if ($pdf)
      return $pdf;
    else
      throw new Exception("Jasper did not return PDF data. Instead got: \n$pdf");
  }
```

The full example I found here https://gist.github.com/26205

The goal it to create something like this:
[image: Jasper Server PHP Client]

Comment: Are you asking for someone to write your code for you? You gotta drill down your question a bit more than "I want a working example of my entire project".

Comment: No, just need to know how to make the attachment of XML data in PHP that is acceptable for Jasper Server.  The rest of it is mostly done, and will be Open Sourced.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an answer, but probably helpful. There is a library called [*WSO2 WSF/PHP*](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/):

> WSO2 WSF/PHP is intended to fill some of the gaps in the PHP extension. WSO2 WSF/PHP is an open source implementation like the SOAP extension and supports MTOM, WS-Addressing, WS-Security, and WS-RelaiableMessaging. WSO2 WSF/PHP supports a similar API to that of the SOAP extension. There are plans to wrap the API to provide the same API of the SOAP extension; it will be written in C.

I think you're looking for *Binary attachment (MTOM)*.

The following links might be useful as well:

- [PHP SOAP Messages with Attachments<sup>*PEAR::SOAP related*</sup>](http://www.casarini.org/blog/2009/php-soap-messages-with-attachments/)
- [MIME Attachments using SoapClient Class<sup>*Mailing List*</sup>](http://old.nabble.com/MIME-Attachments-using-SoapClient-Class-td27539258.html)
- [SOAP Messages with Attachments<sup>*W3C*</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments)
- [PHP SOAP Extension<sup>*Introduction*</sup>](http://wso2.org/library/1060)

Answer (score 0):

[On their own site](http://jasperforge.org/scm/viewvc.php/branches/js-3.5.0/samples/php-sample/?root=jasperserver) they have also some examples about integration to Web Services via php.

Is there any help for this?

Comment: I cant see anything on there about attaching an XML data set to report on

Answer (score 0):

`SOAP` request has no attachment support.

The idea is how you process your request.
The only way I use SOAP requests with attachments is to `Base64 Encode` the data to be attached, and add it to a Text node.

Add the tag with attribute `encoded=`"`true/false"`. If its a file content, supply the name of the file in the request.

In the server side, if you find the node with an attribute `encoded="true"`, You can take the data from the node, Base64Decode it and do what ever you need.

The idea of Base64 is to avoid many special characters that a SOAP request doesn't support in Request. Some SOAP processors have the option with "`encoded`" attribute.

Comment: Apparently you can add attachments to SOAP requests. And it works with Jasper Server according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351511/upload-report-unit-via-webservice-in-c-sharp-net-to-jasperserver

Answer (score 0):

You want to include a xml file in your SOAP query or response?

You could encode it base64 like in emails and then require the user on the other end to decode it.

```
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($xml_data));
```

Then just add it in a seperate xml tag in your SOAP query/response.